# Use the same widget in two different layouts in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

I would like to use the same widget in two different layouts in Qt. Here is my code:

```
QWidget *myWidget = new QWidget;

QFormLayout *layout1 = new QFormLayout;
layout1->addWidget(myWidget);

QFormLayout *layout2 = new QFormLayout;
layout2->addWidget(myWidget);
```

The widget is as it should in `layout2` but is not visible in `layout1`.

A workaround would be to create two different `myWidget` widgets, but I would like to know if there is a better way of doing.

Why does this happen and what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Are you wanting the widget to be shown at two different locations at the same time?

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes (although both layouts won't be visible at the same time)

Comment: If you feel the need of putting the same widget on multiple layout, maybe you should consider splitting that in a model/view design, using two istances of widget pointing to the same model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`addWidget` transfers the ownership from `layout1` to `layout2`.
Object trees are the way Qt uses to organize objects. As an example, an item that has a parent *is displayed in its parent's coordinate system and is graphically clipped by its parent's boundaries*.
You can try to work around the limitation, but it is not how you should use Qt and I won't suggest it.
If you need two widgets, create two widgets. That's how Qt is designed and how it should be used.

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) for further details about the Qt's objects model.

Comment: IIRC layouts don't maintain ownership, they just delegate it to their parents. Note that a layout's parent is a `QWidget` and `QLayout` itself does not derive from a widget, so even in the case of nested layouts, the parent is the bottom most widget. Also, `QWidget`'s parent is a widget too, not `QObject` so a layout could not possibly take ownership of a widget, even if even to me that would make more sense.

Comment: @ddriver `QFormLayout` inherits `QLayout` and the latter inherits `QObject` (at least the documentation says so). `addWidget` calls `addItem` (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem) and, again, the documentation says that - _The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it_. So your reasoning has flaws somewhere.

Comment: @ddriver I read once more your comment. I got what you mean now. Well, the answer still applies, I don't understand how such a comment would require to change it. Are you suggesting to add more details or whatever?

Comment: In inherits `QObject` but not `QWidget`, while every `QWidget` is a `QObject`, not every `QObject` is a `QWidget`. If you do a simple test, you'd realize once you add a widget to a layout, the widget's parent will not be the layout, but the underlying widget. Maybe its just a case of bad documentation, there are plenty examples of such. There is nothing wrong with the answer per se, I am just clarifying.

Comment: @ddriver Yeah, I got it. Thank you for that. I was trying to understand what's the reasoning, that's all. I guess it could be also interpreted as an example of _it is as if_, more than an error in the documentation. It's easier to understand and actually it works _as if_. Anyway, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: The inserted widget will also be included in the underlying widget's children, it does look a lot like the widget taking ownership rather than the layout. I remember noticing that while I was dumping `QObject` trees, the widget technically becoming a sibling rather than a child of the layout.

Comment: It's not bad documentation (well.. maybe it is), as `QLayout::addItem` uses `QLayoutItem` and `QLayoutItem` is not the same as `QWidget`. You can find the part that states that layout's parent will take the ownership of the added widgets [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts). Though I do think that this should be stated in `QLayout::addWidget`'s documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have the same object in multiple places. There is only once instance of it and it lives in only one single location. You can only have multiple references. Granted, a layout doesn't take a widget instance, but a reference (pointer) to it, but Qt's design is such that adding a widget to a layout will transfer ownership to the layout's underlying widget. And it makes sense, the two layouts may call for a different widget geometry, and how does a single widget have two geometries in the same time? Even if possible theoretically, it is not possible without abstracting the geometry away from the widget, and in Qt's case the geometry is part of the widget, so it is not possible. And that's just one of the many aspects which make such reuse/sharing challenging and not really viable.

Depending on what you want to achieve you could:

- reuse GUI elements - in that case roll out `YourOwnWidget : public QWidget`, then you can instantiate in as many times as you want
- share the same data across multiple GUI elements, in addition to the previous step, what you really want to do is put the **data** in a separate, non-visible object, then you can create and bind as many types and instances of GUI elements to it as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QGraphicsView`. Define one instance of `QGraphicsView` and add it to `layout1`:

```
QGraphicsView *gv1 = new QGraphicsView();
layout1->addWidget(gv1);
```

Define another one and add it to `layout2`:

```
QGraphicsView *gv2 = new QGraphicsView();
layout2->addWidget(gv2);

QGraphicsScene *qc = new QGraphicsScene();
qc->addWidget(myWidget);
```

Now set scene to your `QGraphicsView` objects

```
gv1->setScene(qc);
gv2->setScene(qc);
```

After that you have two views containing the same widget.